# How to match fields regex in bash

Tags: regex, bash

Made a regex that matches the field I want to assign to my variable in bash:

The regex is:

```
(\,?[ ]?(\.?\d{1,3}){4})+\ (.*)
```

and the substring I am interested about is $3 (group 3)

Could anyone please give me command line to assign the substring to my variable?

Example:

```
MYVARIABLE=$(echo $FULLSTRING | grep -oP '(\,?[ ]?(\.?\d{1,3}){4})+\ (.*)'
```

But this example obviously did not work

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the input and output string to reproduce it?

Answer (score 1):

You may extract the Group 3 value using Bash regex matching:

```
text="1.23.23.45 This is what I want"
rx='(,? ?(\.?[0-9]{1,3}){4})+ (.*)'
if [[ $text =~ $rx ]]; then
 echo "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
else
 echo "No match!"
fi
```

See the [online Bash demo](https://ideone.com/583eOw) printing `This is what I want`.

If there is a regex match (`if [[ $text =~ $rx ]]`), the contents of Group 3 are in `"${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Perl installed, then you can match against your regex and print the field you want:

```
MYVARIABLE=$(echo $FULLSTRING | perl -nE '/(\,?[ ]?(\.?\d{1,3}){4})+\ (.*)/;say $3')
```

Example:

```
FULLSTRING=', .123.4.5.6 matchthis'
MYVARIABLE=$(echo $FULLSTRING | perl -nE '/(\,?[ ]?(\.?\d{1,3}){4})+\ (.*)/;say $3')
echo $MYVARIABLE
```

Outputs: `matchthis`